# How to get data from the controller model to the view

Tags: jsf, datatable

hi guys sorry to post again but this is really confusing me

i have a query that i can get to run, the user enters a string and then the application will search for this in the database connected to the application, this bit i have working, however now i have successfully run the queury i am unsure of how to retrieve the data from it and be able to use it in the view in a `h:datatable`

currently to do the search, this is what is in the view, the faclet page the user enters

```
<h:inputText id="search" value="#{userdetailsController.search}" />   
                    &nbsp;
                    <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userdetailsController.submit}" ajax="true" />
```

this then goes to

```
@Named("userdetailsController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserdetailsController implements Serializable {

    @EJB

 private String search;

    private List<Userdetails> item; // No need for DataModel here.

    public String submit() {
        item = ejbFacade.searchByString(search);
        return ""; //change this !, testing only
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }
```

then

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;
    private List userList;

/* trying out a search function */
    public List<T> searchByString(String string) {
        System.out.println("in SearchByString");
        return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername").setParameter("username", "%" + string + "%").getResultList();
    }
```

which does the search in

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERDETAILS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetails.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetails u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetails.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetails.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username = :username")})
```

How can i once this process has been completed retrieve the data to print out in the console for example, what do i need to call to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *i am unsure of how to retrieve the data from it*

Your code already does that in the `submit()` method.

---

> *and be able to use it in the view in a h:datatable*

Just add the following to your view, maybe below the command button in the same form, in order to present it:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userdetailsController.item}" var="userdetails">
    <h:column>#{userdetails.username}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And make sure that this is covered in the ajax update of the command button:

```
<p:commandButton ... update="@form" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd only rename the confusing property name `item` to `items` as it represents a collection of items, not a single item. Also, your `submit()` method doesn't need to return an empty string. It can also just be declared `void`. Also, `ajax="true"` is the default already for `<p:commandButton>`, you can just omit it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, the reason it is called item currently is becuase i am using the property name items for something else, however when i try your code i get the error 

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'Richard.jsfClasses.UserdetailsController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'item'.`

where it looks like it can not find `item` but it is there, is there anything i have done wrong

Comment: You forgot to create/generate a getter method for it.